# Javascript closure test- why am I having "undefined" as result?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code -

```
function test1 () {
  let num = 15;

  return function test2 () {
    console.log(num);
    num++;
  }
}

let f = test1();
console.log(f());
console.log(f());
console.log(f());
```

[image]

This is the output I am getting -
[image]

My question is why am I getting the `Undefined` results after each value?

Comment: Because your closure does not return anything, `undefined` is the default return value of functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f` and `test2` don't return a value. What do you expect to see in the console logs? If you add `return num`, then you'll see the numbers printed twice.

```js
function test1() {
  let num = 15;
  
  return function test2() {
    console.log(num);
    num++;
    return num;
  }
}

let f = test1();
console.log(f());
console.log(f());
console.log(f());
```